# Convert javascript object from one form to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapreduce

I have a list of team objects which consists team name, reported by and list of statuses for each day of that team which I would like to convert it into list of date based objects which contains all teams and its status for the respective date.

I have tried something like this which is not giving expected results.

```
teams.map(team => ({
    day: team.statuses.reduce((acc, it) => it.day),
    teams: {
        teamName: team.teamName
    }
}))



 [
   {
      "teamName":"abc",
      "reportedBy": "user1",
      "statuses":[
         {
            "day":"10/12",
            "status":"green"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/11",
            "status":"green"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/09",
            "status":"green"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
      "teamName":"xyz",
      "reportedBy": "user2",
      "statuses":[
         {
            "day":"10/12",
            "status":"red"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/11",
            "status":"red"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/09",
            "status":"red"
         }
      ]
   }
```

]

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "day": "1012",
    "teams": [
      {
        "teamName": "abc",
        "reportedBy": "user1",
        "status": "green"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "xyz",
        "reportedBy": "user2",
        "status": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "day": "1011",
    "teams": [
      {
        "teamName": "abc",
        "reportedBy": "user1",
        "status": "green"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "xyz",
        "reportedBy": "user2",
        "status": "red"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "day": "1009",
    "teams": [
      {
        "teamName": "abc",
        "reportedBy": "user1",
        "status": "green"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "xyz",
        "reportedBy": "user2",
        "status": "red"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think reduce is the best option here. I think it's better to create an empty array and populate as you go:

```js
let input = [
   {
      "teamName":"abc",
      "reportedBy": "user1",
      "statuses":[
         {
            "day":"10/12",
            "status":"green"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/11",
            "status":"green"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/09",
            "status":"green"
         }
      ]
   },
    {
      "teamName":"xyz",
      "reportedBy": "user2",
      "statuses":[
         {
            "day":"10/12",
            "status":"red"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/11",
            "status":"red"
         },
         {
            "day":"10/09",
            "status":"red"
         }
      ]
   }
];

let output = [];

input.forEach(team =>
{
  let name = team.teamName;
  let reporter = team.reporter
  team.statuses.forEach(status =>
  {
    let dayItem = output.find(item => item.day == status.day);
    if(dayItem == null)
    {
      let newItem = {day: status.day, teams:[{status: status.status, reportedBy: reporter, teamName: name}]};
      output.push(newItem);
    }
    else
    {
      dayItem.teams.push({status: status.status, reportedBy: reporter, teamName: name})
    }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: yeah...I have tried something similar, please see my answer below, but I am just wondering if there is a better way

Comment: How do you define better?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like following.

```
  let dayIndexed = {};
  let dayStatuses = [];

  teams.forEach(function(team) {
        team.statuses.forEach(function(status) {
            status.day = status.day.replace(/\//g, '');
            if(!dayIndexed[status.day]) {
                dayIndexed[status.day] = {
                    day: status.day,
                    teams: []
                };
                dayStatuses.push(dayIndexed[status.day]);
            }
    
            dayIndexed[status.day].teams.push({
                teamName: team.teamName,
                reportedBy: team.reportedBy,
                status: status.status   
            });
        });
    });
```